# Program calculating tax rate per line item equaling into VAT

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following df:

```
     quantity#1    unit price#1    line amount#1    line amount#2    line amount#3    line amount#4    VAT
--  ------------  --------------  ---------------  ---------------  ---------------  ---------------  -----
 0           nan           nan                  5              nan              nan              nan   1.05
 2             1          1150.5               10               20               30              nan   6.6
 6             1          2458               2458              nan              nan              nan   0
13             1          1689                 10               20               30              nan   5.4
17             1           260                260               30              100               75  73.05
```

From this DF, I want to extract the tax rate from each specific line rates. The tax rate line items should be calculated dynamically so that each line amount times a certain tax rate totals the VAT amount. The tax rates can be 0.09, 0.21 and 0.00 and should be equal to the VAT (BTW) subset. I've tried the following:

```
x = [0.09, 0.21, 0.00]

for i,row in df.iterrows():
    if row['Document Type'] == 0:
        df['line amount'[i]] * x == df['BTW']
```

however this does not work..

Desired output:

```
      quantity#1    unit price#1    line amount#1    line amount#2    line amount#3    line amount#4    VAT
--  ------------  --------------  ---------------  ---------------  ---------------  ---------------  -----
 0           nan           nan                  5              nan              nan              nan   1.05
 2             1          1150.5               10               20               30              nan   6.6
 6             1          2458               2458              nan              nan              nan   0
13             1          1689                 10               20               30              nan   5.4
17             1           260                260               30              100               75  73.05

#new columns
      taxrate#1    taxrate#2        taxrate#3        taxrate #4    
--  ------------  --------------  ---------------  --------------- 
 0           0.21          nan               nan              nan            
 2           0.21          0.09              0.09             nan            
 6           0.00          nan               nan              nan            
13           0.09          0.09              0.09             nan            
17           0.21          0.09              0.09             0.09
```

Please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 3 different tax rates and 4 line amounts per row, so it can be one of 3**4 = 81 combinations. We can calculate total VAT for each combination, and then find the combination that matches the VAT from the dataframe:

```
from itertools import product

# get all possible tax rate combinations
x = [0.09, 0.21, 0.00]
combinations = np.array(list(product(*[x]*4)))

# get amount columns
amounts = df.filter(like='line amount')

# calculate total VAT for each row for each tax rate combination
vats = amounts.fillna(0).dot(combinations.T).round(1)

# for each row find the combination that gives total VAT
# that is equal to the value in VAT column for that row
ix = vats.eq(df['VAT'].round(1), axis=0).idxmax(axis=1)
taxrates = np.where(amounts.notna(), combinations[ix], np.nan)

# add taxrate columns to the original dataframe
taxrate_cols = amounts.columns.str.replace('line amount', 'taxrate')
df[taxrate_cols] = taxrates

df
```

Output:

```
    quantity#1  unit price#1  line amount#1  line amount#2  line amount#3  \
0          NaN           NaN              5            NaN            NaN   
2          1.0        1150.5             10           20.0           30.0   
6          1.0        2458.0           2458            NaN            NaN   
13         1.0        1689.0             10           20.0           30.0   
17         1.0         260.0            260           30.0          100.0   

    line amount#4    VAT  taxrate#1  taxrate#2  taxrate#3  taxrate#4  
0             NaN   1.05       0.21        NaN        NaN        NaN  
2             NaN   6.60       0.21       0.09       0.09        NaN  
6             NaN   0.00       0.00        NaN        NaN        NaN  
13            NaN   5.40       0.09       0.09       0.09        NaN  
17           75.0  73.05       0.21       0.09       0.09       0.09
```

Comment: added to my question here :) : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66824922/script-calculating-tax-rate-per-line-item-equaling-into-vat

Comment: With the following df: I'm getting incorrect results

Comment: {'line amount#1': {0: 18.15, 2: 260.0, 4: 260.0},
 'line amount#2': {0: nan, 2: nan, 4: 30.0},
 'line amount#3': {0: nan, 2: nan, 4: 12.5},
 'line amount#4': {0: nan, 2: nan, 4: nan},
 'VAT': {0: 3.81, 2: 54.6, 4: 63.53}}

Comment: @Max The problem here is rounding, e.g. 18.15 * 0.21 = 3.8115, which is not exactly 3.81. I've added `.round(1)` to `vats` and made a change to compare it to `df['VAT'].round(1)` (`1` for 1 decimal places). Please see my updated answer above

Comment: One more thing. If we may have cases when our combinations fail to give the VAT that we're searching for, it currently returns the first value, which is 0.09 (like in your examples above without rounding). We could change the `x` to be `x = [np.nan, 0.09, 0.21, 0.00]`, then if no combination matches our VAT, it would return `np.nan`, making it easier to debug (but a little less computationally efficient)

Comment: Perl, hope you are well! I'm struggling to add a column 'shipping' to the code equalling shipping costs. How would you go about and do this? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you have a list with values already? `df['shipping'] = list_shipping`, assuming the order in both is the same. Or did I misunderstand the question?

Comment: Thanks for your help perl. Truly appreciated. I have a variant of this question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67460068/program-calculating-tax-rate-per-line-item-equaling-into-exclvat . Would be truly epic if you could help

Comment: @Max I think it's basically the same logic, but after finding the tax rates, we need to calculate amounts excluding tax (so, multiplying by (1 - taxrate)). There was a bit of a problem with rounding in your new example, so I've updated the code to make it a bit more robust in finding the answer with the highest accuracy (see my answer to that new question). Hope it helps!

Comment: @Max Actually, it is a little more accurate if we calculate it based on `ExclVAT` like you suggested, updated my answer (for the new question)