# Program calculating tax rate per line item equaling into ExclVAT

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

Imagine you have the following df:

```
d = {'line amount#1': [5.95], 'line amount#2': [5.95], 'line amount#3': [15.75],'line amount#4': [15.75], 'line amount#5': [3.9]
    ,'line amount#6': [2.9], 'line amount#7': [np.nan], 'line amount#8': [np.nan], 'line amount#9': [np.nan],'line amount#10': [np.nan]
    , 'BTW':[5.85],'ExclVAT':[44.35], 'Totaal': [50.2]}
dfcalc = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
dfcalc
```

Tabulate showing line amount#1 and #10 only:

```
+----+-----------------+------------------+-------+-----------+----------+
|    |   line amount#1 |   line amount#10 |   BTW |   ExclVAT |   Totaal |
|----+-----------------+------------------+-------+-----------+----------|
|  0 |            5.95 |              nan |  5.85 |     44.35 |     50.2 |
+----+-----------------+------------------+-------+-----------+----------+
```

From this DF, I want to extract the tax rate from each specific line rates. The tax rate line items should be calculated dynamically so that the line amounts divided by a certain tax rate total the ExclBTW amount when the line amounts are added together. The tax rates can be 0.09, 0.21 and 0.00 and should be equal to the VAT (BTW) subset. I've tried the following:

```
from itertools import product

# get all possible tax rate combinations
x = [1.09, 1.21, 0.00]
combinations = np.array(list(product(*[x]*10)))

# get amount columns
amounts = dfcalc.filter(like='line amount')

# calculate total VAT for each row for each tax rate combination
vats = amounts.fillna(0).dot(combinations.T).round(1)


# for each row find the combination that gives total VAT
# that is equal to the value in VAT column for that row
ix = vats.eq(dfcalc['ExclVAT'].round(1), axis=0).idxmax(axis=1)
taxrates = np.where(amounts.notna(), combinations[ix], np.nan)
```

There is a variant of this question answered by @perl:[Program calculating tax rate per line item equaling into VAT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66784496/program-calculating-tax-rate-per-line-item-equaling-into-vat)
However not coming any further..

Desired output are the line amounts divided by the taxrates equalling into ExclVAT:

```
+----+-----------------+------------------+-------+-----------+----------+
|    |   line amount#1 |   line amount#2  |   BTW |   ExclVAT |   Totaal |
|----+-----------------+------------------+-------+-----------+----------|
|  0 |            4.92 |              4.92|  5.85 |     44.35 |     50.2 |
+----+-----------------+------------------+-------+-----------+----------+
```

Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a bit of a problem here with rounding, no combination of taxrates actually gives us exactly the right answer.

I've updated the code to find the combination that gives us the most accurate number that can be achieved:

```
from itertools import product

# get all possible tax rate combinations
x = [0.00, 0.09, 0.21]
combinations = np.array(list(product(*[x]*10)))

# get amount columns
amounts = dfcalc.filter(like='line amount')

# calculate amounts excluding VAT for each row for each tax rate combination
exclvat = amounts.fillna(0).dot((1 + combinations.T)**-1)

# for each row find the combination that gives amounts excluding VAT
# that is equal to the value in ExclVAT column for that row
ix = np.abs(exclvat.sub(dfcalc['ExclVAT'].squeeze(), 0)).idxmin(1)
taxrates = np.where(amounts.notna(), combinations[ix], np.nan)

# subtract tax from line amounts
dfcalc[amounts.columns] /= (1 + taxrates)
dfcalc['line amount sum'] = dfcalc.filter(like='line amount').sum(1)
dfcalc.T
```

Output:

```
                         0
line amount#1     4.917355
line amount#2     4.917355
line amount#3    14.449541
line amount#4    14.449541
line amount#5     3.223140
line amount#6     2.396694
line amount#7          NaN
line amount#8          NaN
line amount#9          NaN
line amount#10         NaN
BTW               5.850000
ExclVAT          44.350000
Totaal           50.200000
line amount sum  44.353628
```

Comment: Thank you perl ! You have been very helpful. I wish you a nice fruitful day, thank you, Max

Comment: Hi Perl, quick question if possible. When loading a large dataset (n=10) into the code you get the following error:IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices
Would you know how to fix this?

Comment: Which line of code results in that error?

Comment: So it is :
---> 17 taxrates = np.where(amounts.notna(), combinations[ix], np.nan)

Comment: OK, so it's probably about `ix`. What does `ix` look like? (maybe just the output of `ix.head()`)

Comment: Sure, ofcourse: 0   NaN
1   NaN
2   NaN
3   NaN
5   NaN
dtype: float64

Comment: OK, doesn't look good... let's try replacing our current `ix = ...` with `ix = np.abs(exclvat.sub(dfcalc['ExclVAT'].squeeze(), 0)).idxmin(1)` (updated in my answer above, so you can copy the full code if needed)

Comment: Thank you perl! This is working nicely:
ix.head() now becomes: 0    1045845
1    1048405
2    1048565
3     349525
5     349525
dtype: int64

Comment: Have a great evening

Comment: Cool, glad that it helped! A bit surprising though that you get `1045845`. How many `line amount`s do you have? (`ix` should only be a maximum of `59049` for 10 line amounts)

Comment: Thanks perl. That's weird, I'm using 10 line amounts but with different input data than stated in the question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232305/discussion-between-max-and-perl).